# How can I get children in a tree map from MongoDB to show up as an array inside a children key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

I'm trying to achieve an output that resembles JSON where children in a tree map show under an object's "children" key. The reason I'm asking is because I'm using Primefaces (PrimeVue) and need to use the TreeTable component to show a family tree. The output needs to look something like this:

```
[
                  {
                    key: '0',
                    data: {
                        name: 'Applications',
                        size: '100kb',
                        type: 'Folder'
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            key: '0-0',
                            data: {
                                name: 'Vue',
                                size: '25kb',
                                type: 'Folder'
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    key: '0-0-0',
                                    data: {
                                        name: 'vue.app',
                                        size: '10kb',
                                        type: 'Application'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: '0-0-1',
                                    data: {
                                        name: 'native.app',
                                        size: '10kb',
                                        type: 'Application'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: '0-0-2',
                                    data: {
                                        name: 'mobile.app',
                                        size: '5kb',
                                        type: 'Application'
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                
]
```

The current code I have is this:

```
const fetchTrees = (source, root) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                User.find({referrer: source}).then((children) => {
                    const promises = children.map((person, index) => {
                        const child = {
                            name: person.first_name + ' ' + person.last_name,
                            uppLine: person.uppLine,
                            _id: person._id
                        }
                        children.push(child)
                        root[index] = child
                        return fetchTrees(person._id, root[index])
                    })
                    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
                        if (results[0] !== null || results[0] !== undefined) {
                            resolve(root);
                        } else {
                            reject("No tree data");
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
                })
            })
        }
```

The output for this is:

```
{
    "0": {
        "name": "Anthony Quinn",
        "_id": "6515c57828f1601db4024deb"
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "Peers Morgan",
        "_id": "6515cc4280981f87ecd90598"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Quick Silver",
        "_id": "6515cd95bac94d41880dd091"
    },
    "3": {
        "0": {
            "0": {
                "name": "Chris Mark",
                "uppLine": "100",
                "_id": "6520d88203d9eb1f9f0a092a"
            },
            "name": "Adam Curry",
            "uppLine": "100",
            "_id": "6518846650762f0c69a16bfb"
        },
        "name": "Larry David",
        "_id": "651778cb1c60e355b88c3df6"
    },
    "4": {
        "name": "Hugh Jackman",
        "_id": "6515cf42a982c9a36ebc3505"
    },
    "5": {
        "name": "Rihanna Rihanna",
        "_id": "6515cfa73b15e4debcb13a1a"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the output only has object notation and there are no children arrays being outputted.